# Intuition for no isometric embedding of round projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^4 $

Tags: riemannian-geometry, isometry, submanifold

According to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231495/examples-of-two-dimensional-riemannian-manifolds-that-cant-be-isometrically-emb there is no smooth isometric embedding of the round (=constant positive curvature) projective plane into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $.

**Is there some intuition for why there is a smooth isometric embedding into $ \mathbb{R}^5 $ and even into round $ S^4 $ but not into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $?**

Some things I already know:

- There is an isometric embedding of round $ \mathbb{R}P^n $ into $ \mathbb{R}^{N} $ where $ N=\frac{n(n+3)}{2} $
- This embedding is equivariant with respect to the isometry group $ O_{n+1} $ at least for $ n=1,2 $. In fact the image of the embedding arises as the orbit of a vector with respect to an $ N $ real dimensional irreducible orthogonal representation of $ O_{n+1} $.
- It is an open question if there exists a $ C^r $ embedding of $ \mathbb{R}P^2 $ into $ \mathbb{R}^4 $ for $ 1 < r <2 $